# Microsoft word does not displays document correctly

Tags: microsoft-word

I use Microsoft Word 2016.

My Microsoft Word started showing documents like this:
[image]

It shows every document like this. I think I accidentally changed some settings. How can I fix this?

Comment: @harrymc my was the first. But I edited HazardousGlitch answer it and after accepted. Now I will delete my answer. You saw it in the process of deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like **Show field codes instead of their values** is probably checked. Try this:

Go to: **File** menu -> **Options** -> **Advanced**. Scroll down to  **Show document content** section and uncheck **Show field codes intead of their values**

**Source:** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/hyperlinks-in-word-2007-are-showing-up-in-brackets/b6f1d302-42ae-4372-856e-daa730a367ab

Screenshot: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhiaF.png]